# How to get the country code from mobile number using php

Tags: php, country-codes, mobile-country-code

i am getting mobile number from database in database i am haveing more the 1000 mobile numbers,my database look like this

```
   mobilenumber
   971525478965
   919844005522
   45712345678
```

i want to go through each number in the database and find the `countrycode` from the mobile number display the `countrycode` and the country using php

for example  like this

```
 countrycode 971 country UAE
 countrycode 91 country India
 countrycode 45 country Denmark
```

any one has any suggestions please guide me how to do it.

i tried like this ,but want to check more than one mobilenumber from database

```
 <?php

$number = "971527139011";

    $countrys = array(

    '1' => 'us',
    '2' => 'uk',
    '3' => 'de',
    '44' => 'fi',
    '123' => 'no',
    '971' =>'uae',
    '91' =>'india',
    '92' =>'pakistan'
    );

    $i = 4;
    $country = "";
    while ($i > 0) {
        if (isset($countrys[substr($number, 0, $i)])) {
            $country = $countrys[substr($number, 0, $i)];
            break;
        } else {
            $i--;
        }
    }
    echo $country;


    ?>
```

edited

```
   <?php


$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '1234fedf';
$dbDatabase = 'smsmobile';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

$sql = "SELECT destinationaddress FROM reporting";
//print $sql;

$queryRes1 = mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($queryRes1))
{
$destinationaddress[] = $rows['destinationaddress']; 

}



$phones = $destinationaddress;



// get your list of country codes
$ccodes = array(
    '1' => 'us',
    '2' => 'uk',
    '3' => 'de',
    '44' => 'fi',
    '123' => 'no',
    '971' =>'uae',
    '91' =>'india',
    '92' =>'pakistan'
);

krsort( $ccodes );

foreach( $phones as $pn )
{
    foreach( $ccodes as $key=>$value )
    {
        if ( substr( $pn, 0, strlen( $key ) ) == $key )
        {
            // match
            $country[$pn] = $value;
            break;
        }
    }
}

print_r( $country );    
    ?>
```

Comment: Take the first 3 numbers and check if they match a country code. If not, check the first two. If still no match, check only the first?

Comment: i did but i want to go through the numbers in database can i use while loop...

Comment: You can get a full list of country codes and phone numbers from http://country.io/data if you don't have one already

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
// get your list of numbers from DB
$phones = array( '971527139011', '171527139011' );

// get your list of country codes
$ccodes = array(
    '1' => 'us',
    '2' => 'uk',
    '3' => 'de',
    '44' => 'fi',
    '123' => 'no',
    '971' =>'uae',
    '91' =>'india',
    '92' =>'pakistan'
);

krsort( $ccodes );

foreach( $phones as $pn )
{
    foreach( $ccodes as $key=>$value )
    {
        if ( substr( $pn, 0, strlen( $key ) ) == $key )
        {
            // match
            $country[$pn] = $value;
            break;
        }
    }
}

print_r( $country );
```

*Edit*

The data is pretty messy, I suggest you store it in different columns, but, if the structure of the data is always the same, this will extract the country/code from it:

```
$data = array( 'country : Denmark prefix:45', 'country : Pakistan prefix:92' );

foreach ( $data as $string )
{
    $_a = explode( ':', $string );
    $_b = explode( ' ', $_a[1] );
    $ccode[$_a[2]] = $_b[1];
}

print_r( $ccode );
```

Comment: it is working fine but i want to take all mobile number from database ans check can u guide me

Comment: thanks i am trying to get data from database please see my updated code its not working

Comment: here is $ccodes is defined manually in an array but i am have in database like country and prefix i want to take that country and prefix and put inside the $ccodes can you help me,thanks for the help

Comment: example: of database  country : Denmark  prefix:45 i want it take it from database and put it in side of $ccodes and compare with the number

Comment: `$destinationaddress[] = $rows['destinationaddress'];` whats the content of this array once you fill it?

Comment: please see my code its working fine fine but i want to take cccode from database the database contain  'country : Denmark prefix:45'

Comment: Edited, but please, take some effort on your own to figure this one out. It's not that hard.

Comment: if you there i need another help from you $string = 'country : Pakistan prefix:92'; but i want display the values from database in the string i have more that 100 values in database can you you guide how to put all values in string .

Comment: Just add another `foreach`.